# How do I pass in calculated values to a list sort using numba.jit in python?

Tags: python, jit, numba

I am trying to sort a list using a custom key within a numba-jit function in Python. Simple custom keys work, for example I know that I can just sort by the absolute value using something like this:

```
import numba

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def myfunc():
    mylist = [-4, 6, 2, 0, -1]
    mylist.sort(key=lambda x: abs(x))
    return mylist  # [0, -1, 2, -4, 6]
```

However, in the following more complicated example, I get an error that I do not understand.

```
import numba
import numpy as np


@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def dist_from_mean(val, mu):
    return abs(val - mu)

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def func():
    l = [1,7,3,9,10,-4,-2,0]
    avg_val = np.array(l).mean()
    l.sort(key=lambda x: dist_from_mean(x, mu=avg_val))
    return l
```

The error that it is reporting is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testitout.py", line 18, in <module>
    ret = func()
  File "/.../python3.6/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 415, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "/.../python3.6/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 358, in error_rewrite
    reraise(type(e), e, None)
  File "/.../python3.6/site-packages/numba/core/utils.py", line 80, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: convert make_function into JIT functions)
Cannot capture the non-constant value associated with variable 'avg_val' in a function that will escape.

File "testitout.py", line 14:
def func():
    <source elided>
    l.sort(key=lambda x: dist_from_mean(x, mu=avg_val))
                                                ^
```

Do you know what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you know what is happening here?

By using the parameter `nopython = True` you deactivate the object mode and hence Numba isn't able to handle all values as Python objects (refer to: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/glossary.html#term-object-mode). (Reference is actually another post I coincidentally wrote today: [How call a `@guvectorize` inside a `@guvectorize` in numba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65353407/how-call-a-guvectorize-inside-a-guvectorize-in-numba/65426862#65426862))

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def func():
    l = [1,7,3,9,10,-4,-2,0]
    avg_val = np.array(l).mean()
    l.sort(key=lambda x: dist_from_mean(x, mu=avg_val))
    return l
```

Anyhow, `lambda` is "too" complex for a numba jit function - at least when it's passed as an argument (compare https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4481). With the `nopython` mode activated you can only use a limited amount of libraries - the full list can be found here: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html

That's why it throws the following error:

> numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step:
> convert make_function into JIT functions) Cannot capture the
> non-constant value associated with variable 'avg_val' in a function
> that will escape.

Moreover, your referencing a jit accelerated function within another - when having `nopython = True`. That could be the source of the problem as well.

I'd highly suggest taking a look at the following tutorial: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html#will-numba-work-for-my-code; it should help you out with similar problems!

---

**Further reading and sources:**

- https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/5120
- http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html#will-numba-work-for-my-code
- [TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55065419/typingerror-failed-in-nopython-mode-pipeline-step-nopython-frontend)
- https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4481
- https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html
- [How call a `@guvectorize` inside a `@guvectorize` in numba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65353407/how-call-a-guvectorize-inside-a-guvectorize-in-numba/65426862#65426862)

Comment: So how would you recommend custom sorting a list with such a function in a jit function?