# Numba - TypingError: Cannot capture the non-constant value associated with variable in a function that will escape

Tags: python, python-3.x, numba

I am new to Numba, so sorry if this is simple problem.  I tried using Numba for a function for the first time, but I get "TypingError: Cannot capture the non-constant value associated with variable in a function that will escape."  I have searched for this error, but I do not find anything to understand what it means and how to fix.

I am calling a jitted function like this:

```
FindDynamicTPSLs(TADF_TP1,TAAction, 1, 'TP')
FindDynamicTPSLs(TADF_SL1,TAAction, 1, 'SL')
FindDynamicTPSLs(TADF_TP2,TAAction,2, 'TP')
FindDynamicTPSLs(TADF_SL2,TAAction,2, 'SL')
FindDynamicTPSLs(TADF_TP3,TAAction,3, 'TP')
FindDynamicTPSLs(TADF_SL3,TAAction,3, 'SL')
FindDynamicTPSLs(TADF_TP4,TAAction,4, 'TP')
FindDynamicTPSLs(TADF_SL4,TAAction,4, 'SL')
```

TADF_TP1 is a dataframe,
TAAction = is a string,
1,2,3,4 are a ints,
TP is a string,

The variable the error refers to is the integer, and it gives me no further information in the log.

What does this error mean and what should I do different?

Here is the body of the function:

```
@jit(nopython=True, nogil=True, parallel=True)#,debug=True)
def FindDynamicTPSLs(TADF1,taAction,RBNum,Type):
    global DynamTPs
    global DynamSLs
    global DynNumDF
    global TPStartValue
    global SLStartValue
    global TATicketNum
    global TAOpenPrice
    global DF1RBColList
    global DF1RBCompreColList
    global DF2RBColList
    global DF2RBCompreColList
    global DF3RBColList
    global DF3RBCompreColList
    global DF4RBColList
    global DF4RBCompreColList
    global MergeColList1
    global DynamTPColmns
    global DynamSLColmns

    @jit(nopython=True, nogil=True, parallel=True)
    def LowerDTSize(TADF_copy):
        global TPStartValue
        global SLStartValue

        if RBNum == 1:
            ComprList = DF1RBCompreColList
        elif RBNum == 2:
            ComprList = DF2RBCompreColList
        elif RBNum == 3:
            ComprList = DF3RBCompreColList
        elif RBNum == 4:
            ComprList = DF4RBCompreColList

        if Type == 'TP':
            if taAction == 'Buy':
                TADF_copy = TADF_copy[(TADF_copy[ComprList] > TPStartValue)]# & (TADF_copy[DF1RBCompreColList] < TADF_copy['High'])]# & (TADF_copy[DF1RBCompreColList] > TADF_copy['PrevHigh']) & (TADF_copy[DF1RBCompreColList] > TADF_copy['PrevClose'])]
                return TADF_copy
            else:
                TADF_copy = TADF_copy[(TADF_copy[ComprList] < TPStartValue)]# & (TADF_copy[DF1RBCompreColList] > TADF_copy['Low'])]# & (TADF_copy[DF1RBCompreColList] < TADF_copy['PrevLow']) & (TADF_copy[DF1RBCompreColList] < TADF_copy['PrevClose'])]
                return TADF_copy
        else:
            if taAction == 'Buy':
                TADF_copy = TADF_copy[(TADF_copy[ComprList] < SLStartValue)]# & (TADF_copy[DF1RBCompreColList] > TADF_copy['Low'])]# & (TADF_copy[DF1RBCompreColList] < TADF_copy['PrevLow']) & (TADF_copy[DF1RBCompreColList] < TADF_copy['PrevClose'])]
                return TADF_copy
            else:
                TADF_copy = TADF_copy[(TADF_copy[ComprList] > SLStartValue)]# & (TADF_copy[DF1RBCompreColList] < TADF_copy['High'])]# & (TADF_copy[DF1RBCompreColList] > TADF_copy['PrevHigh']) & (TADF_copy[DF1RBCompreColList] > TADF_copy['PrevClose'])]
                return TADF_copy

    #pdb.set_trace()
    if RBNum == 1:
        ColList = DF1RBColList
        ComprList = DF1RBCompreColList
    elif RBNum == 2:
        ColList = DF2RBColList
        ComprList = DF2RBCompreColList
    elif RBNum == 3:
        ColList = DF3RBColList
        ComprList = DF3RBCompreColList
    elif RBNum == 4:
        ColList = DF4RBColList
        ComprList = DF4RBCompreColList

    TADF_copy = TADF1[ColList].copy()
    TADF_copy = TADF_copy.set_index('Date_Time')
    TADF_copy2 = LowerDTSize(TADF_copy)
    TADF_copy2 =TADF_copy2[ComprList]
    TADF_copy2 = TADF_copy2.dropna(axis = 1, how = 'all')
    TADF_copy2 = TADF_copy2.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'all')
    TADF_copy = TADF_copy[MergeColList1]
    TADF_copy = TADF_copy.merge(TADF_copy2, how = 'outer', left_index = True, right_index = True, suffixes = (None,'2'))
    TADF_copy.reset_index(inplace = True)
    DfName = Type + RBNum
    #pdb.set_trace()
    for i in TADF_copy.index:
        rowSeries = TADF_copy.iloc[i]
        rowSeries = rowSeries.dropna()
        rowSeries = rowSeries.iloc[7:]
        CndlHigh = TADF_copy._get_value(i,'High')
        CndlLow = TADF_copy._get_value(i,'Low')
        PrevCndlClose = TADF_copy._get_value(i,'PrevClose')
        PrevCndlHigh = TADF_copy._get_value(i,'PrevHigh')
        PrevCndlLow = TADF_copy._get_value(i,'PrevLow')
        ColTime = TADF_copy._get_value(i,'Date_Time')
        for x in rowSeries:
            colval = x
            if Type == 'TP':
                if taAction == 'Buy':
                    if  colval > CndlHigh or colval < CndlLow or colval < PrevCndlHigh or colval < PrevCndlClose:
                        continue
                    else:
                        TimeColName = 'Dynamic_TP_'+str(DynNumDF[DfName])+'_lane_Time'
                        PriceColName = 'Dynamic_TP_'+str(DynNumDF[DfName])+'_lane_Price'
                        DynamTPs._set_value(TATicketNum, TimeColName, ColTime)
                        DynamTPs._set_value(TATicketNum, PriceColName, colval)
                        #pdb.set_trace()
                        return
                else:
                    if colval < CndlLow or colval > CndlHigh or colval > PrevCndlLow or colval > PrevCndlClose:
                        continue
                    else:
                        TimeColName = 'Dynamic_TP_'+str(DynNumDF[DfName])+'_lane_Time'
                        PriceColName = 'Dynamic_TP_'+str(DynNumDF[DfName])+'_lane_Price'
                        DynamTPs._set_value(TATicketNum, TimeColName, ColTime)
                        DynamTPs._set_value(TATicketNum, PriceColName, colval)
                        return
            else:
                if taAction == 'Buy':
                    if colval < CndlLow or colval > CndlHigh or colval > PrevCndlLow or colval < PrevCndlClose:
                        continue
                    else:
                        TimeColName = 'Dynamic_SL_'+str(DynNumDF[DfName])+'_lane_Time'
                        PriceColName = 'Dynamic_SL_'+str(DynNumDF[DfName])+'_lane_Price'
                        DynamSLs._set_value(TATicketNum, TimeColName, ColTime)
                        DynamSLs._set_value(TATicketNum, PriceColName, colval)
                        return
                else:
                    if colval > CndlHigh or colval < CndlLow or colval > PrevCndlHigh or colval > PrevCndlClose:
                        continue
                    else:
                        TimeColName = 'Dynamic_SL_'+str(DynNumDF[DfName])+'_lane_Time'
                        PriceColName = 'Dynamic_SL_'+str(DynNumDF[DfName])+'_lane_Price'
                        DynamSLs._set_value(TATicketNum, TimeColName, ColTime)
                        DynamSLs._set_value(TATicketNum, PriceColName, colval)
                        return
```

Comment: What is the body of the function `FindDynamicTPSLs`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass in calculated values to a list sort using numba.jit in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63794635/how-do-i-pass-in-calculated-values-to-a-list-sort-using-numba-jit-in-python)

Comment: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html#will-numba-work-for-my-code  In the post you provided, it linked to this URL.  It says that Numba does not know what dataframes are, but I don't know if that means using them or just creating them (their example was creating a dataframe).  But when I turn nopython=False, it still gives same error.  So I don't think it answered my question, unless the answer is doesn't work with dataframes.